# Is there any way to count the no. of blank rows in csv file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have used fast-csv module and it only has the option to ignore the empty rows but I need to count the empty rows.

```
    csv
    .fromPath(importFile.path, {
        headers: true,
        ignoreEmpty: true
    })
    .on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code I am seeing you are already half way there. Just initialize a `count` variable at the top and in the callback of "data" event split the lines in array and check if the row is empty, based on your requirement.

```
function getEmptyRows(csv){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let emptyRows = 0;

        csv
        .fromPath(importFile.path, {
            headers: true,
            ignoreEmpty: true
        })
        .on("data", (data) => {
            const lines = data.trim().split(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g);

            lines.forEach((line) => {
                if(line.match(/([^\s,])/)){
                    count++;
                }            
            });
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            return resolve(count);
        });
    });
}
```

And you can use the function above in the following ways-

```
getEmptyRows(csv).then((count) => {
    // do your operation...
});

// or as an async/await

async () => {
    const count = await getEmptyRows(csv);
    // do your operation...
}
```

Comment: data is of buffer type and when converted to a string  it has something like this [object Object]

Comment: use can easily convert buffer to string by using `data.toString()`, assuming `data` is the buffer. More:  https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html